# Call A JavaScipt Method From <apex:commandButton> Instead of call by a html Button

Tags: visualforce, javascript, commandbutton

Is it possible to call **javaScript** from `<apex:commandButton>` ...?

Comment: check this post http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/10463/18731

Comment: Hello Ratan ,
I Know that but i need to call h javascript method via <apex:commandbutton>

Comment: hv you tried anything what Frodo answer ? that will work and also the above post having same ans that should work

Comment: ya and my answer was cleared @ that tym i have asked nd i was saying about your like that you have shared :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apex:commandbutton` supports `onclick`.So yes you can call javascript method.
try this: `<apex:commandButton value="Save" onclick="saveMethod();"  />`

If you want to pass the parameters in JS metohd.You can do this:

```
onclick="DisplayErr('{!Account.Name}');"
```

Comment: Sir actually it is not working ... :(

Comment: Check my updated answer. Share your code if you need more information on this.